# Centering RadioButtons

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

I have two RadioButtons in a Radio Group that look like so.
[image]

```
             <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_PubAsMe"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="Self"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_PubAsTeam"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Team"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </RadioGroup>
```

By default, android justifies to the left, I want to have these buttons centered. When I try to set the gravity for each button to the center, the following happens.

[image]

Same Code but added this line to each RadioButton

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? How can I get the button to move to the center with the text?

```
   |---------(Button)Text---------|---------(Button)Text---------|
```

Comment: `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: I have tried this, does not do anything.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "How can I get both the button and the text to move to the center?" Kind of open to interpretation.

Comment: I have edited my question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does this look?

[image: Centered RadioButtons]

I used a few invisible RadioButton "spacers". (Code below)

---

I also tried various combinations with only one "spacer"... (and I switched to the "Light" theme in a quick attempt to mimic your color scheme.)

[image: White Centered Buttons]

But the top image looks more centered and balanced to me than the bottom one.

---

This is the code for the top layout.

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_PubAsMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Self" />

    <RadioButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_PubAsTeam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Team" />

    <RadioButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RadioGroup>
```

---

If you prefer the bottom image simply remove the first and last "spacers" and remove the `layout_weight` attributes. Hope that helps!

Comment: Great Trick! I figured out a way, that pretty much looks the same, but I will try your method out.

Comment: I used the above answer, with a bit of a modification for margins. The second RadioButton's text varies in length so I had to adjust.

Comment: I see but when you rotate the device to landscape or even use a device with bigger screen the margins don't adjust automatically... This design should be more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code.

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_PubAsMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Self"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_PubAsTeam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Team"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RadioGroup>
```

It works as desired

Comment: I believe you are missing the space between the RadioButtons.

Comment: Right. I have missed this point. My code center them within a main layout however the margins left and right are not the same as the space between the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i can think of is the the following:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Repeat the above RelativeLayout --> 
</LinearLayout>
```

You can't put the buttons in a RadioGroup this way, but it looks like you wanted it to look.